# Solutions for Mass Dynamic Virtual Hosting

Tags: php, apache2, virtualhost

After a couple days of trying different solutions, I'm looking for ideas for dynamic virtual hosting.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

- I've got multiple clients each accessing their own site with their own subdomain (i.e. companyx.website.com)
- Each client is assigned one of several document roots depending on the version of the application that they're running.  Their database and client files are brought in by php depending on the subdomain.
- New clients may set up a site via web interface.

I could have a script generate virtual host configs for apache2 and link/unlink them to sites-enabled, with each config sending the client to their version's document root. But this requires script root access and apache restarts, and I don't like creating this many hard files.

I have tried mod_vhost_dbd, with clients mapped to document roots in the mysql db.  This would work great except I really need mod_rewrite to have pretty urls (i.e. http://www.website.com/login becomes http://www.website.com/index.php/login).  mod_vhost_dbd with this rewrite causes an internal redirect loop.

I can envision having one vhost in apache, then doing some routing in php depending on the subdomain.  I'm not sure what that would look like though...

Any ideas for this?  I'm also not opposed to switching to another server such as nginx, but I haven't been convinced that would help the situation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I have an answer for you :)

We use mod_vhost_alias, and had the same issue with redirect loops.  The solution, is to make sure your redirect urls are absolute instead of relative.  I.e.  They start with a "/".

i.e.

```
RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
```

You do:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /app/webroot/    [L]
```

Or:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
```

Curious, what did you do?  We currently have a SaaS offering, and we are creating a new DocumentRoot for each new deployment (using mod_vhost_alias).  And we are looking for a new way to conserve disk space.  We are looking at mod_vhost_dbd, or sticking with mod_vhost_alias with symlinks but haven't decided.  We want something that scales well for High Availability Setups, and symlinks doesn't seem like a good long term solution.